# How to Fix Missing System Settings Icons In Ubuntu

Tags: system-settings

When I take system settings I am getting the following

[image]
After that I tried following commands

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

But when I try these, I am getting an error "failed to fetch. size mismatch"

I can't even change my system brightness.

How can I solve it?